# How to plot Intensity of SmoothKernelDistribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

For example, we have a list of values

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10^3];
```

then

```
SmoothHistogram[data]
```

By default plot the PDF of `data` like this

[image]

But there is also options to plot the `Intensity` of data using

```
SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "Intensity"]
```

which gives

[image]

This intensity curve is what I want. But I also want the function of this intensity curve, so I can to subtract two such intensity curve function to plot a new one.

I look into the doc, it seems that `SmoothKernelDistribution` suite the needs. For example, let

```
dist=SmoothKernelDistribution[data]
```

then

```
Plot[PDF[dist, {x}], {x, -3, 3}]
```

gives

[image]

Which is equivalent to `SmoothHistogram[data]`. But how to get equivalent Intensity plot using `SmoothKernelDistribution`? Is there a complete list of function that is supported by `SmoothKernelDistribution` like `PDF`?

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[0];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10^3];

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax@data;

smhist = SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "Intensity"]
```

[image]

```
p[x_] = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data], x];
```

The factor required to scale the `PDF` to the intensity curve is

```
amp = Divide @@
   ((Cases[#, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1, All, 2]] // 
        Max) & /@
     {smhist, Plot[p[x], {x, xmin, xmax}]});

intensity[x_] = amp*p[x];

Plot[intensity[x], {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** A more straightforward approach is to use the points from `smhist` to define an [`InterpolatingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html).

```
int = Interpolation[Cases[smhist, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]]];

Plot[int[x], {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, powerful postprocessing. So there is no built in statistic function corresponding to "indensity"?